# Setting delegate for a property that's has a default value from a closure

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, initialization

I have a collection view that's a class property and I want to set it up like this:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let cv = UICollectionView()
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    return cv
}()
```

However this gives me the error that self is not of type UICollectionViewDelegate/UICollectionViewDataSource which makes sense because the closure is not that type. What I'm wondering if it's possible to reference the class instance from inside the closure? Or should I just set the delegate and datasource in a different method? I've searched for a solution but haven't found anything about setting the delegate through a closure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the property from `var` to `lazy var`, as lazy properties are initialised only when they are used for the first time. So this will fix your problem.

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let cv = UICollectionView()
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    return cv
}()
```